# Client-Server in C++ in Eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, compilation

My code consists of a "server.cpp" "server.h" "client.cpp" "client.h" and then a "echo-client.cpp" and a "echo-server.cpp". Echo is just the name of the program. It is supposed to receive a message and echo it back. Obviously both the echo-client and the echo-server have a main function.

In java I would just run the server then the client. That is what I'd like to do know but in C++. It doesn't seem like eclipse behaves the same with C++ as it does with Java.

What am I missing?

Comment: So what happens when you try to run the server and then the client? All you've said is 'it doesn't work', you need to say a bit more about exactly what does happen.

Comment: As far as I can find, there is no where in eclipse to run them separately. This really is more of an eclipse question

Comment: It's been a while since I've used Eclipse for C++, but have you put the two programs in separate projects? If not then that's probably a good idea.